# How to check java file usage in project and dependencies using Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

I want to check whether Java file is used through out Project and module in netbeans. Always i need to right click on project and find class name  which is tedious.

Can't we check java file usage in some other straightforward option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to *search and open file* in Netbeans. To open file by class name you can also go with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>.